# OpenSSL decrypt AES-ECB-256 encrypted password - can't figure out the right syntax

Tags: encryption, openssl, cryptography, aes, ctf

I am trying to decrypt aes-256-ecb encoded password using OpenSSL with the following (captured during a ctf only) informations:

```
##PASS_16##
oRnS7llE9q3utIvyP1rbK4OPVDjOPdEss36jsgu/Yvfh9yx0qR530oV8eLH9fxw2
AES-ECB-256
Key : thisIsTheSharedKeyIShouldKeepOK!
```

From what I gathered I understood that :

- ecb mode doesn't have an IV to be specified
- the ciphertext is base64 encoded so need to decide it before decryption
- as my key is long enough, it doesn't need padding

**decoded_cipher.txt** contains the result of the following command :

```
echo "oRnS7llE9q3utIvyP1rbK4OPVDjOPdEss36jsgu/Yvfh9yx0qR530oV8eLH9fxw2" | base64 -d > decoded_cipher.txt
```

**key.txt** :

```
thisIsTheSharedKeyIShouldKeepOK!
```

**hex_key.txt**

```
7468697349735468655368617265644b65794953686f756c644b6565704f4b21
```

this openssl command :

```
openssl enc -aes-256-ecb -d -in decoded_cipher.txt -out decrypted.txt -K 7468697349735468655368617265644b65794953686f756c644b6565704f4b21 -nopad
```

gives me this error :

> bad decrypt 40678142ED7F0000:error:1C80006B:Provider
> routines:ossl_cipher_generic_block_final:wrong final block
> length:../providers/implementations/ciphers/ciphercommon.c:429:

The final result should follow the following pattern :
PASS_16{*alphanumerical_message*})
or
*alphanumerical_message*

Does someone have an idea on how to decipher this encrypted message properly ?

Comment: Don't encrypt passwords. Hash them. See [tag:password-encryption] for why.

Comment: @user207421 what do you mean "_Don't encrypt passwords_" ??? I am trying to **decrypt** the message, not encrypt it.

Comment: Your openssl enc command worked just fine for me without error (although it didn't result in the expected format)

Comment: Check that decoded_cipher.txt is the expected length. It should be exactly 48 bytes. That error can occur with ciphers where the ciphertext length is not a multiple of the block size (16)

Comment: @MattCaswell I juste checked decoded_cipher.txt's size and it's exactly 48 bytes.

Comment: @MattCaswell I don't know what I did wrong but you're right, the openssl enc work just fine, same as you. But it didn't decrypt the message. Do you have any idea what should I do next ?

Comment: Figure out why the key is wrong (and/or wrong cipher is being used)

Comment: that is exactly why I came to ask for help on stackoverflow. Thanks @MattCaswell